# Multiple OR conditions for an IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Am I doing the multiple OR conditions for an IF statement the right way?

```
var A0minWidth = 841;
var A0minHeight = 1189;

var A0minWidthBleed = 847;
var A0minHeightBleed = 1195;

UploadedDocNameHeightMM = //(get it from the database)
UploadedDocNameWidthMM = //(get it from the database)

if(UploadedDocNameHeightMM < parseFloat(A0minHeight) || UploadedDocNameWidthMM < parseFloat(A0minWidth) || UploadedDocNameWidthMM > parseFloat(A0minWidthBleed) || UploadedDocNameHeightMM > parseFloat(A0minHeightBleed)) 
{
       //do this
       alert ("Yes! one of those.")
}
```

Help!

Comment: You can easily test this.

Comment: That depends on what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Yep, double pipes are correct. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what your code is supposed to do of course, but syntactically this is correct - e.g. no need to wrap each each expression that is an operand to the logical-OR operators in parentheses like this:

```
if ((UploadedDocNameHeightMM < parseFloat(A0minHeight)) || (UploadedDocNameWidthMM < parseFloat(A0minWidth)) || (UploadedDocNameWidthMM > parseFloat(A0minWidthBleed)) || (UploadedDocNameHeightMM > parseFloat(A0minHeightBleed)))
{
    alert("Yes! one of those.");
}
```

Also, the `||` operator will short-circuit evaluate.  Basically it will not evaluate expressions to the right of any expression that evaluates to `true`.

For more information on `||` and other JavaScript logical operators including examples check out [Mozilla's overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) or search on JavaScript logical operators.

Comment: You gave some great insights. I am looking at the link. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help, @Matthew.  We all have to start somewhere and have basic questions.  I try to be encouraging and helpful.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Hi @J0e3gan, I want to short-circuit the condition even if one of the || is true and enter into the loop and do the rest. So, am I on the right track?

Comment: Short-circuiting with `||` means that as soon as a Boolean operand is `true`, we know the condition is logically `true` and do not evaluate any further Boolean operands.   Similarly, as soon as a Boolean operand is `false` with `&&` short-circuiting, we know that the condition is `false` and do not evaluate any further Boolean operands.

Comment: Thanks a lot @J0e3gan. Very helpful. Not sure why someone vote down my question.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct.

However:

- parseFloat is not necessary here
- Are you sure the two first tests are correct (==> Don't you need to check if UploadedDocNameHeightMM > A0minHeight instead of < ?)

Comment: Thanks @Sebcap26 I have to check 4 conditions here: Height should be less than 841 nor greater than 847 and Width should not be less than 1189 nor greater than 1195. So, each side has min and max value.